# Beamer Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \frame{\titlepage}

Tags: beamer

I am having the following error: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \frame{\titlepage}. The code is:

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}%blackandwhite
\usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%gráficas
\usepackage{graphics}%gráficas
\usepackage{hyperref}%hypervinculo
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{multicol}%varias columnas
\newtheorem*{ejem}{Ejemplo} 
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposición}
\newtheorem*{teor}{Teorema}
\newtheorem*{defin}{Definición}
\newtheorem*{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem*{algoritmo}{Algoritmo}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corolario}

 \mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Hannover}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{img.eps}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
   \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}  

\title[\textsc{ }]{\textrm{ABBB}} 
\author[\textsc{}]{\textsc{SSSS}}   
\institute[]{ \textsc{s\\ SSSSS}\\ \vspace{0.3cm}}  
\date{}

%\AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[current]}}

\begin{document}
%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}%Estilo de bibliografia
\frame{\titlepage}
%\part{Talk}
%\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[part=1]}

\section{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Slide 1 
\begin{frame}{Contents} 
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item A
        \item Ac
        \item Dc
        \item Fcn
        \item Hc
        \item Hc
        \item Gc
    \end{enumerate}

\pause 

\end{frame}
\part{Talk}
\section{Overview}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Slide 2 
\begin{frame}{Overview}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    asbdf
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It very much looks like the instruction `\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}` is causing the subsequent breakdown. I must confess to not having a clue what this instruction is supposed to achieve. Do omit it and see if you can live the result.

Comment: Please remove the packages and usetheorems that aren't needed to reproduce the example.  We're all having a hard time understanding the purpose of the complicated def.  Is it part of the problem?  If not, remove it.  If it is part of the problem, why do you have it?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Mico.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}% OR \usetheme{Berkeley}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{% 
\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{title}
   text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Error:**

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).<to be read again> cl.15 \end{frame}
```

Note: If you write **Warsaw** theme, the above code is not error.

Write the following command to count the slides:

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}
```

Edit your file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}%blackandwhite
\usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%gráficas
\usepackage{graphics}%gráficas
\usepackage{hyperref}%hypervinculo
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{multicol}%varias columnas
\newtheorem*{ejem}{Ejemplo} 
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposición}
\newtheorem*{teor}{Teorema}
\newtheorem*{defin}{Definición}
\newtheorem*{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem*{algoritmo}{Algoritmo}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corolario}

 \mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Hannover}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{img.eps}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}

%\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
%   \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}  


\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

\title[\textsc{ }]{\textrm{ABBB}} 
\author[\textsc{}]{\textsc{SSSS}}   
\institute[]{ \textsc{s\\ SSSSS}\\ \vspace{0.3cm}}  
\date{}

%\AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[current]}}

\begin{document}
%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}%Estilo de bibliografia
\frame{\titlepage}
%\part{Talk}
%\frame{\frametitle{Index}\tableofcontents[part=1]}

\section{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Slide 1 
\begin{frame}{Contents} 
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item A
        \item Ac
        \item Dc
        \item Fcn
        \item Hc
        \item Hc
        \item Gc
    \end{enumerate}

\pause 

\end{frame}
\part{Talk}
\section{Overview}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Slide 2 
\begin{frame}{Overview}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    asbdf
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Suggestion: See the [answer1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73718/frame-numbering-in-warsaw-theme) , [answer2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155684/how-can-i-modify-the-beamer-footline-in-a-way-that-doesnt-change-positioning-of) to the question  And [Beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/).

Edit:
On the **Hannover** theme
`\useoutertheme[height=0pt,left]{sidebar}` used. with

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{% 
\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

Has created a problem!
Indeed with `\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber`

**Edit end:**
Change **Hannover** theme
`\useoutertheme[height=0pt,left]{sidebar}` to

```
\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=0pt,left]{sidebar}
```

Not error Minimal code.

Comment: I don't quite follow.  What was the problem with the complicated def?  What is the solution, other than commenting out the offending lines?  (It doesn't help that we don't know what the complicated def was trying to do.)

Comment: @Teepeemm.Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. but the comand does not show the slide number: \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}

Comment: @ MIlena .ouput show the slide number. Texlive 2019.